# Work statistics report for resources

Tags: ms-project, reporting, ms-project-2010, project-charter

I have a master file with several sub-projects and resources assigned to them.
Is there a way to make a bar chart in Project Pro report that shows the work hours for resources based on the sub-projects they're working on (outline level:level 2)?

I just simply can't get the chart to show Level 2 outline as a parameter result.

[image]

Attached is a mock-up chart.

Thank you kindly for your assistance and have a great weekend

Comment: Are you using Project 2013 or Project 2010?

Comment: I'm using Project Pro 2010. I'll try to create the chart per your instructions, thank you Julie!

Comment: Great.  Let us know how you get on.

Comment: It worked! thank you so much, you saved me :D

Comment: You're welcome, Millie T and thank you for the feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some tweaking you can get the chart from the Baseline Work Visual report.  Open the master project you created using the pool and create the Baseline Work visual report.

Once the data is in Excel make the following changes:

1. Turn off the display of Actual Work and Baseline Work in the Pivot table field list.
2. Turn on Resources in the Pivot table field list.  They should be added to Row.
3. Drag the Tasks from Rows to Columns.
4. Turn off the Weekly Calendar

Your chart should now look like:
[image]

I hope this helps.